# Flexbox with dynamic padding and item count is not resizing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have created a flexbox where the items should change size dynamically with the padding according to the window size. Unfortunately sometimes i am not able to control the amount of items on a row, it randomly goes back and for between the state of aligning correctly and sometimes incorrectly. I am very convinced that there is a typo somewhere in the code. When i sometimes choose an amount of items, i usually get it minus one.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKPxBx

```js
$('#slider1, #slider2').change(function(event, ui) {
  setItemsOnRow(parseInt($('#slider1').val()), parseInt($('#slider2').val()));
  console.log($('#slider1').val() + " " + $('#slider2').val())
});


function setItemsOnRow(itemCount, paddingSize) {
  const offset = 0;
  var innerWidth = $(window).innerWidth() - paddingSize * (itemCount + 1);
  console.log("body: " + innerWidth);
  var maxItemWidth = innerWidth / itemCount - offset;
  var maxItemHeight = maxItemWidth;

  // All items
  $('.item')
    .css("margin-top", paddingSize)
    .css("margin-left", paddingSize / 2)
    .css("margin-right", paddingSize / 2)
    .height(maxItemHeight)
    .width(maxItemWidth);
  $('.item:nth-child(' + itemCount + 'n+1)')
    .css("margin-right", paddingSize / 2)
    .css('margin-left', paddingSize)
  $('.item:nth-child(' + itemCount + 'n-' + itemCount + ')')
    .css("margin-right", paddingSize);

}
```

```css
.control {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.45s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
  <label for="slider1">Items</label>
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" />
  <br/>
  <label for="slider2">Padding</label>
  <input id="slider2" type="range" min="0" max="50" step="5" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *When i sometimes choose an amount of items, i usually get it minus one*: I guess you can solve this using *`{box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: You didn't divide paddingSize by 2 in this line:  `.css('margin-left', paddingSize)` . Also consider using the CSS counter() function for the item count, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your items have something like this:

```
element.style {
    margin-left: 7.5px;
    margin-right: 7.5px;
}
```

But several items have this:

```
element.style {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 7.5px;
}
```

or this:

```
element.style {
    margin-left: 7.5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Obviously, when items wrap, these uneven margin settings will cause items to misalign.

For the columns to align, your left and right margins have to be equal for all items.

(The margin values posted above are for one particular setting in your app. These values change depending on the padding setting. However, the pattern is stable: some items have equal horizontal margins, others have double on the left or right.)